# Ionic: How is it possible to change $ionicPopup subTitle's text programmatically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I'm trying to change the value as well as the style of the subText attribute associated with an $ionicPopup somewhere in my app.

I searched everywhere, but didn't find yet any method for doing so.

So how is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change popup after it been shown,
you can use selectors and angular jqlite wrapper.

Code is like this

```
onTap: function(e) {
          var result = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-sub-title");

           angular.element(result).html('dsaadsds')
           e.preventDefault();
        }
```

You have [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QELEoL) a working codepen.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, but that's not what I'm asking for. What I want to know is: *how to change the value of the subTitle 'Please use normal things'*.

Comment: Can you explain what you try to change?

Comment: As I've explained above, I want to change the value of the subTitle. I mean more exactly, how to change the value of the subtitle that I've already defined, programmatically inside the `onTap` function.

Comment: I change answer as you need

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for. Thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the `subTitle` directly using the configuration option, as by defined in the [specification](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/) it accepts an optional `String` value

> {
>     title: '', // String. The title of the popup.
>     cssClass: '', // String, The custom CSS class name
>     subTitle: '', // String (optional). The sub-title of the popup.
>   }

**UPDATE:**

You can assign a value to a `$scope` property within `onTap` to assign a success message

```
{
    text: '<b>Save</b>',
    type: 'button-positive',
    onTap: function(e) {
      $scope.success = {
        message: 'Hello World!'
      };

      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

And now you can access `$scope.success.message` to show the success message

Comment: So if I want to display a success message on that $ionicPopup without changing the subtitle. What's the recommended method for doing so?

Comment: Do you mean on tapping save on the popup?

Comment: See my answer it's possible by html selectors

Comment: @ygalbel That's not a very clean way of doing things. If its required, you can create a directive to wrap this functionality

Comment: You right that's not clean, but to create a directive for only this feature seems to be a little overkill

Comment: @ygalbel Not an overkill at all. You should not be fiddling with DOM within your service methods

Comment: @user6039980 See the update section for your other question

Comment: @AdityaSingh I tried what you've recommended, but it didn't work for me.